# profiles_details.id does not exist Django

Tags: python, django

Hi I am having an issue with profiles_details.id does not exist

I have created  a custom profile... I dont want users to access the admin so I set this to false. On sign up a user is saved in djangos USER_AUTH models and a redirect occurs to a profile form.

My code: Models

```
 class Details(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    about  = models.CharField(max_length = 500)

    etc...
```

The form:

```
 class detailsStep1(forms.ModelForm):

"""
Step 0 of Profile Creation.
"""
   name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,label="Name")

   surname = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput,
                            label="Surname")

   country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,
                            label="Country")

   state = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,
                            label="State/Provience")

   city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,
                            label="city")

   statusType =  forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True,
                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,      
                         choices=Details.STATUS_TYPE_CHOICES)

class Meta:

    model = Details
    fields = ['name', 'surname', 'country',  
                                       'state','city','statusType']
```

The View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext

from profiles.forms import detailsStep1


   def steps1 (request):


        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = detailsStep1(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return redirect('/admin/')
    else:
            form = detailsStep1()
    return render_to_response('profiles/step1.html', {
            'form': form,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Below is the error message and trace

```
ProgrammingError at /profiles/steps1
column profiles_details.id does not exist
 LINE 1: ...25:15.417979+00:00'::timestamptz, 0, 0) RETURNING     "profiles_...
                                                         ^
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/steps1
 Django Version:    1.8.5
 Exception Type:    ProgrammingError
 Exception Value:   
 column profiles_details.id does not exist
 LINE 1: ...25:15.417979+00:00'::timestamptz, 0, 0) RETURNING   "profiles_...
                                                         ^
Exception Location: /home/g4/django/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
  Python Executable:    /home/g4/django/envRU/bin/python
  Python Version:   3.4.3
  Python Path:  
 ['/home/g4/django/ru/ruV03/rulinked',
  '/home/g4/django/envRU/lib/python3.4',
  '/home/g4/django/envRU/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
  '/home/g4/django/envRU/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
   '/usr/lib/python3.4',
   '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
   '/home/g4/django/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
   Server time: Mon, 26 Oct 2015 23:25:15 +0000
```

Any points would be great. I have run migrations and even tried a new database and deleted cache and pyc files in the project. I have no created a signal for the profile form as I assume it would only be needed in binding profile data for the admin area (still quite new to django)

Thank you

Comment: Sir. could you provide us the `/profiles/steps1` view? and if it is not asking too much, fix your indent guides on the codes?

Comment: Thank you I have included the view.

Comment: @RamonMoraes [I am having the same proglem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370751/how-to-use-the-costumuser-in-modles-py-and-views-py-applications) after I created a costume User model

Comment: @red8alice did you solved it?