# Django foreign keys : settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL keeps giving null for form.save

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms

I have read articles and tried to implement in models.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

but whenever I try to save a form for the user it states that the value cant be null. I assume because its not passing/picking up the AUTH_USER

for example:

```
class Degree(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    degreeLevel = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

     areaOfStudy = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

I have a feeling that on user creation I need to create a signal for all models that use  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) but I am struggling to find resource that deals with this issue from start to finish, so I not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help would be great...

This question relates [profiles_details.id does not exist Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357505/profiles-details-id-does-not-exist-django)

Thank you.

I have tried :

user =  models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, 
       on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_(u"User"))
But got an error message when running migrations of :

```
 NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

if I take the verbose nameout and try migrate I get:
this error:

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to details without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Also looked at 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

But didnt understand what to do with:

```
 django.contrib.auth.get_user_model().
```

Comment: Have you actually set the user value to anything when you create a new Degree?

Comment: no I haven't, im not sure how to do so, i assumed that django would get the login /signup user and fill that space with settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) as tutorial dont really get into that... If you could point me to one or explain that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several details to target in your question:

1. If you want your `user` field to be not mandatory, you should change to:

   ```
    user = models.ForeignKey (..., null=True,...)
   ```
2. If you want to solve the problem about `_` not being recognised, you should add the following import on top of your file:

   ```
     from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
   ```
3. If you want populate your `user` field in a view, you could do it as follows:

   ```
    from django.views.generic import View

    class MyView(View):
        ...

        def get(request, *args, **kwargs):

            myobject = Degree.objects.get(...) # do some query 
            myobject.user = request.user
            myobject.save()

            return ...
   ```

   assuming your view handles a get request and wants to assign the current user to the object user.
4. about how to use: `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` here is an example

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

   ...


   def create_user(username, first_name, last_name, *args, **kwargs):

       user_class = get_user_model()
       new_user = user_class.objects.create(username=username,
           first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
   ```

   basically, the `get_user_model` function returns you the class that you configured in `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. from it you can access, for example, its managers (e.g. `objects`) and query or create new instances.

Comment: Thank you very much that was useful... :)